# Is ~/.profile run when connecting remotely with xrdp?

Tags: xfce

Environment: Running Xubuntu desktop, with default xsession set to xfce4 (`echo 'xfce4-session' > ~/.xsession`)

After logging in remotely (from Windows via Remote Desktop Connection) my path is not setup as expected from the contents of my `~/.profile`, is that expected? Should `~/.profile` be loaded in this scenario?

Comment: Depends on whether your login manager reads it, what login manager are you using? Also, do you have a `~/.bash_profile` file?

Comment: For display manager I chose `lightdm` during the `xubuntu-desktop` installation. That seems to be the login manager: `$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`: `/usr/sbin/lightdm`

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry, I meant display manager. OK, I _think_ lightDM does read `~/.profile` normally. Do you have a `~/.bash_profile`? And where are you checking the path? You open a GUI terminal?

Comment: no `~/.bash_profile` file. I check `echo $PATH` with the desktop (GUI) terminal but the paths that should be added according to `~/.profile` are not present.

Comment: So either `.profile` isn't read or it's misconfigured. Is the path as you expect if you open a terminal, run `. ~/.profile` and then `echo "$PATH"` again? Also try adding something like `touch /tmp/xxx` into `~/.profile` and then log in and see if the file `/tmp/xxx` is created.